# balcony footings

Tags: footings

My husband and I are building a balcony. We opted for a steel beam which allows for 2 posts supporting the 20 foot spread. The architect's plans (for which we've already acquired the building permit) calls for:

6"x6" PT post
on 12" diameter poured concrete footing
on 40"x40"x16" poured concrete caisson
4'0" below grade

What are the steps to achieve this?

1. can we use an open box caisson
2. what kind of rebar or mesh should be added to the caisson (amount and distance apart)
3. do we pour and let the 40x40x16 caisson dry for a few days and then add the 12" footing  ***OR***  do we pour the caisson and footing at the same time

Comment: The rebar size and spacing are something the Architect will have to specify for you- there are no "standard" rebar layouts. You will also need (I assume) some pretty heavy duty brackets poured into the footing to fasten and secure  the 6x6 posts to. I would pour both the caisson and the footing at the same time.

Comment: Check your plans again… I suspect the rebar is already specified somewhere. If it wasn’t, the permits people should have asked for clarification.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate it sounds like the OP wants to change the substructure design from what the archy spec'd—change from poured footing to box caisson (which are precast, AFAIK).  But it's possible she doesn't know the actual terminology.